# cant fit two dropdownmenubutton in a row

Tags: dart, flutter

when i try to add two dropDownFormField in a row its showing an exception i don't know why they are not fitting into a row. i tried to wrap it also not working.when add two dropDown buttons in a row it works perfectly.but i want use validator so i am using dropdownformfield

```
Widget collgDD= Wrap(children:<Widget>[Row(
children:<Widget>[DropdownButtonFormField(
value: selectedcollg,
items: collg.map((value){
  return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(child: Text(value),
  value: value,);
}).toList(),
hint: Text("select ur collg"),
onChanged: (value){
 setState(() {
        selectedcollg=value;
      });
},
),
DropdownButtonFormField(
value: selectbranch,
items: branch.map((value){
  return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(child: Text(value),
  value: value,);
}).toList(),
hint: Text("select ur collg"),
onChanged: (value){
 setState(() {
        selectbranch=value;
      });
},
)
])]);
```

Comment: Please give a little bit of love to code indentation and capital letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flexible` widget

```
 Widget collgDD = Row(children: <Widget>[
  Flexible(
    child: dropdown1
  ),
  Flexible(
    child: dropdown2,
  )
]);
```

Comment: aww it worked but on phone screen it showing right overflowed by 24 pixels

Comment: what is the parent widget ? Use column -> Expanded -> Row